# Wrong area plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to draw a plot from this table:

```
ip   Min             Std
0    19.86764349     97.20356138
16   19.86764349    250.079659
22   19.86764349    168.2253117
23   19.86764349    169.2514577
33   19.86764349    142.664228
...
996  0.371543541    1.52E-07
997  0.371543312    1.85E-07
998  0.371543276    1.73E-07
999  0.371543154    1.97E-07
1000 0.371542976    1.99E-07
```

The code is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      scale only axis,
      enlargelimits=false,
      stack plots=y,
      area style
      ]
      \addplot[] table [x=ip,y=Min] {dataTablaEstadisticas.dat}; closedcycle;
      \addplot[draw=none,fill=green!50] table [x=ip,y=Std] {dataTablaEstadisticas.dat}; closedcycle;
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I can't find my mistake. Any advice, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command is `\closedcycle` (with a backslash), and it needs to be given inside the `\addplot ... ;` command, before the semicolon.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      scale only axis,
      enlargelimits=false,
      stack plots=y,
      area style
      ]
      \addplot[] table [x=ip,y=Min] \dataTablaEstadisticas \closedcycle;
      \addplot[draw=none,fill=green!50] table [x=ip,y=Std] \dataTablaEstadisticas \closedcycle;
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```